# Excel swapping two strings in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, shell

I am trying to swap two strings in whole workbook (all sheets) in Excel. I was trying to replace but this doesn't help me. For example:

I want to make all "Apple" texts "Banana" and same time make all "Banana" texts "Apple". How to do this?

Comment: why? what are you trying to achieve from this...

Comment: 1. Make all apple texts *blah-blah-blah*. 2. Make all *banana* texts *apple* with Replace (Ctrl+H). 3. Make all *blah-blah-blah* texts *banana*.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. It is a solution but with 3 steps.

Comment: @birdcage Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088388/swap-values-with-if-conditions-in-excel

Comment: If that's too many steps, just put it in a macro then?  What have you tried? @Jeeped provided a really simple and quick solution...What makes it not a good solution?

Comment: Well, that's 3 steps more than you've attempted so far.

Comment: did you "do a barrel roll"?

Comment: @Jeeped thats very classical way that I have attempted so far but anyway thanks.

Comment: Put a red ball in one hand, a blue in the other. Now try swapping them over in less than 3 steps, where each hand can only hold one ball at a time. 3 steps *is* the minimum - as suggested by @Jeeped

Comment: There is no in-built "swap" function, so @Jeeped solution is by far the easiest and best way of doing it for one swap. For many swaps a VBA macro may be quicker in the long run (but behind the scenes would still take at least 3 steps). One work-around (if you don't care about case) would be to use case-sensitive search and swap from e.g. all lower case to all upper case. This would require everything to be in the same case to start off with though.

Comment: @CLR Not the best example. 1- You can throw them to the air same time. 2- Catch them in same time. So can be in 2 steps.

Comment: @birdcage Unless you specify a step to catch the relevant ball in the 'other' hand, you're not going to swap with that 2 step process. Besides, 'at the same time' is not something Excel is capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Easy! You just need to loop through all your cells and check for apples and bananas. To do this more efficiently we will use arrays to make things so much faster

Loop through each sheets used range, if cell is "apple" we make it banana, move on, if cell is "banana", we make it "apple". After used range is parsed, we paste back the array to cells.

```
Public Sub ApplesToBananas()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cellArray() As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        cellArray = sh.UsedRange.Value
        For lRow = 1 To UBound(cellArray)
            For lCol = 1 To sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                If LCase(cellArray(lRow, lCol)) = "apple" Then
                    cellArray(lRow, lCol) = "banana"
                ElseIf LCase(cellArray(lRow, lCol)) = "banana" Then
                    cellArray(lRow, lCol) = "apple"
                End If
            Next lCol
        Next lRow
        sh.UsedRange.Value = cellArray
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Now it will throw an error if you have any empty sheets or sheets with only 1 not empty cell. Good luck!

Comment: As I mentioned, you should not have empty sheets, or sheets with only 1 cell with values to run this code.